# What is value of 'if not' in the code?

Tags: python

I'm learning Python and a bit confused what `if not` doing in the below code? I presume `if not` is like `else` statement. But it turns out I'm wrong.  What is the value of `if not exists` in this code? Also another naive question, the variable `exists` is defined within a for loop, why is it available globally?

```
import scrabble
import string

for letter in string.ascii_lowercase:
    for word in scrabble.wordlist:
        exists = False
        if letter * 2 in word:
            exists = True
            break
    if not exists:
        print(letter)

print(exists) # Globally exists = True
```

Comment: No, it is an `if` statement, where the condition is `not exists`. Also, Python doesn't have block scope, so for-loops do not have their own scope. Read more about Python scope-rules [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/291978/short-description-of-the-scoping-rules)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some explanations:

```
import string

# let's create our own wordlist
wordlist = ["cat","moose"]

# Loop all letters from a-z
for letter in string.ascii_lowercase:
    # Inner-loop all words in wordlist
    for word in wordlist:
        # Start with exists = False
        exists = False
        # If letter is repeated break the inner loop and set exists = True
        if letter * 2 in word:
            exists = True
            break
    # Check if exists is False (which it is if double letter didn't exist in any word)
    if not exists:
        print(letter)

# This will print the last exists value (True if 'z' is doubled in any word else false)
print(exists)
```

Since the only letter that is repeated in any of the words in wordlist is 'o': All letters except 'o' is printed out followed by a False

```
a
b
c
d
...
False
```

---

BTW, you can get the same result with this code snippet:

```
import string

doubleletters = []
wordlist = ["cat","moose"]

# Loop through wordlist and extend the doubleletters list
for word in wordlist:
    doubleletters.extend(i[0] for i in zip(word,word[1:]) if len(set(i)) == 1)

print('\n'.join(i for i in string.ascii_lowercase if i not in doubleletters))
```

Answer (score 0):

In python not flips the value of a boolean (true or false) expression. `if not x` can be read as "if x is false", so the statements inside the if block will execute if `exists` is equal to `False`, that is, if no repeat letters have been found.

Comment: More precisely, `not` can work on *any* type of object in Python. So, `not obj` returns `True` if `obj` is *falsey*, and otherwise it returns `False`.